# SharePoint Online auth certification does not work on other PC/environments

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to follow some steps defined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning

I create a certification on my SharePoint tenant via:

```
Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName "PnPFlowDemo" -Tenant "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" -DeviceLogin -Out .
```

I will get my clientID and cert on my PC. I try locally to see if I can authenticate:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId "eefd899b-...." -CertificatePath "C:\Users\myUser\myCert.pfx" -Tenant "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
```

And it works. However, soon as I change environment, such as Azure function or another PC, it does not work.

Here is how it looks in Azure:

```
 Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId "eefd899b-...." -CertificatePath "D:\home\site\wwwroot\Provisioning\Provsionering.pfx" -Tenant "contosot.onmicrosoft.com" -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
```

I get error, suggesting that I was unable to connect:

```
2023-08-27T16:05:15Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: The certificate path is correct.
2023-08-27T16:05:15Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.Internal.NullScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
2023-08-27T16:05:15Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.ProjektProvisionering' (Succeeded, Id=8bed0e0e-8670-42d8-bb20-8c4b34b9f08e, Duration=182ms)
2023-08-27T16:05:15Z   [Error]   ERROR: The current connection holds no SharePoint context. Please use one of the Connect-PnPOnline commands which uses the -Url argument to connect.
```

Function uses PowerShell core 7.2. I have set up the requirements.psd1 in appfiles such as

```
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'.
    'Az' = '5.*'
    # For the latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell'.
    'PnP.PowerShell' = '1.*'
}
```

What can be wrong?